# After authorization send access token and refresh token to website or app in React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, webview

**PROBLEM**: I am trying to send access token and refresh token to the front end after authorizing in the backend. Currently, I am sending the user to this link(https://frontend.com/authorize?access_token=xxxxxx&refresh_token=xxxxxx) which contains access_token and refresh_token. There are two primary issues with this:

1. This does not take into account native apps universal deep linking (or deferred). **Question here is: How do I achieve both web and app redirect with this system**. Creating a whole another backend for mobile apps seems like a headache for no good reason.
2. Another is a security issue, sending access tokens and refresh tokens in the query creates a huge security risk for the user. **What is the most secure way to send the data from backend to frontend?**

What I am thinking to do:

1. Here I am thinking to identify what the browser is and storing it in localstorage. And when the user is redirected to https://frontend.com/authorize?access_token=xxxx&refrsh_token=xxxx, I check for cookies and redirect to the app if the device is Android or iOS. But I am not sure if this is the best idea considering Chrome in mobile phones also sends deviceName as Android in the "react-native-device-info" package.
2. I am blank on this part. Any help will be appreciated.

To clarify, I am not a computer science student. All I have learned in these few months is from SO and Github. Hence, the questions might seem naive to you. But if there is any clarification issue, I will clear it ASAP.